# Get order from KnockoutJS viewmodel based on Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to get an order from a `KnockoutJS` `viewmodel`, but having a hard time getting this done.

This is what the `viewmodel` looks like:

```
{"Orders":
[{"Id":16,"Status":2,
"Products":
    [{"Id":14,"OrderId":16,"Price":5},
    {"Id":15,"OrderId":16,"Price":10},
    {"Id":16,"OrderId":16,"Price":20},
    {"Id":17,"OrderId":16,"Price":30}]},

{"Id":17,"Status":2,
"Products":
    [{"Id":18,"OrderId":17,"Price":0}]}
]}
```

This is one of my many tries:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$(document).on("click", ".btnDetails", function () {
    var oId = $(this).attr('id');

    debugger;

    var order = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.Orders(), function (item) {
        return item.Id === oId;
    });
});
```

How can I get the complete `order` with `Id` 16?

This is not an `observableArray()`, there are no mutations done. This will only serve as showing the details of an order in a Modal (Twitter Bootstrap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code should work just fine, except that your `arrayFirst()` function has an error.  You should have

```
var order = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.Orders(), function(item) {
    return item.Id() === oId;
});
```

Because you mapped your viewmodel properties, comparing the Id of item will still be comparing the ko function.  You need to get the value and compare that directly.  Once you've done that, order should be the first order that matches the id.

Comment: Got my `order` filled with the fix you gave me. But I had to change the `===` to `==` to get the order, otherwise it was `null`. I read about the difference of these equal signs, but I still don't get it. Why does everyone else use `===` inside a `ko.utils.arrayFirst()` and get results, while I don't use it, and get result !?

Comment: The === doesn't do a type conversion; so doing "3" === 3 will return false, but "3" == 3 will return true. I used === when I reconstructed your page and it worked fine.  My guess is Id() is returning a number and oId is probably a string. If you convert oId to a number or Id() to a string (assuming my guess is right), === should work out just fine. In this case == should be fine for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by the complete order. but have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/XrYUb/)

**EDIT**
re-reading the question again its starting to make sense to me. 
To get a reference to the order

1. add a selectedOrder observable to your viewmodel.
2. then add a function showOrder that takes in an the order. and set the selectedOrder to the incomming item
3. on the tag that contains the order data-bind to the click.

and that should get you pretty close to what I believe you need as the selectedOrder will contain all the products as well for display purposes

**HMTL**

```
<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: data.Orders">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <h3 data-bind="click: $parent.showItem">
        Order <span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
    </h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var model = {
    "Orders": [{
        "Id": 16,
            "Status": 2,
            "Products": [{
            "Id": 14,
                "OrderId": 16,
                "Price": 5
        }, {
            "Id": 15,
                "OrderId": 16,
                "Price": 10
        }, {
            "Id": 16,
                "OrderId": 16,
                "Price": 20
        }, {
            "Id": 17,
                "OrderId": 16,
                "Price": 30
        }]
    },

    {
        "Id": 17,
            "Status": 2,
            "Products": [{
            "Id": 18,
                "OrderId": 17,
                "Price": 0
        }]
    }]
};
var selectedOrder = ko.observable();

function showItem(item) {
    selectedOrder(item);
    alert("Selected Order: " + item.Id());

}

var vm = {
    data: model,
    showItem: showItem,
    selectedOrder: selectedOrder
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(vm);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Comment: In your example, you demonstrate it with a predefined model. How can I pass this: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` as the model? `data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` doesn't work. Also, I've tried to implement it like this, but having a hard time getting that `data-bind` thing to work which is placed in the h3 tag.

Comment: `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` should be all that is required.  As for the data-bind thing, I noticed that I forgot to close the `ul` tag in the html supplied. How is `data-bind` giving you a hard time? Also [http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html](Click Binding Documentation) helped me a lot.